# Filling textarea with local storage contents

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to use getItems() to get data from local storage, so that when the user refreshes the page the contents of the text area will still be there. I am a beginner so I am a bit lost.

```
saveBox.on("click", function () {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $("textarea").each(function () {
        // set a variable to select the textareas attributes
        var hour = $(this).attr("hour");
        //console.log(hour)
        //set a variable to select value of users input at certain hour
        var plans = $(this).val();
        //console.log(plans);
        //i saved the hour's plan to local storage
        localStorage.setItem(hour, plans);
        //var hourInput = localStorage.getItem(hour)
    });
});
```

Comment: im just out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, loop over all the textareas and use `.val` to set its value to the stored value.

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
    $(this).val(localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('hour')));
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hykxLrp0/)

Comment: Thank you soo muchhh. i cant believe it was that simple. At one point i did go in the right direction but i did not use the val method

Comment: @AndrésRamírez No problem.

Comment: @AndrésRamírez Would you mind accepting my answer if it solved your issue?